# Payara setup together with sniffy profiler

Tags: glassfish, sniffy

I'm trying to profile application running on Payara server with Sniffy profiler.

Maven dependency is added and file web.xml is modified according to the [documentation](https://github.com/sniffy/sniffy).

I have added sniffy.jar to the `payara\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\` folder.

I have modified glassfish-resources.xml file as follows:

```xml
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/Agenda" object-type="user" pool-name="AgendaPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="AgendaPool" non-transactional-connections="false" ping="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" pooling="true" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-cache-size="0" statement-leak-reclaim="false" statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="sniffer:jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>    
    <property name="User" value="XXX"/>
    <property name="Password" value="XXX"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="io.sniffy.MockDriver"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

I'm able to see HTTP methods response times but not queries response times:
[No query response time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Smp.png)

Is my configuration correct? Why there are no response times for executed queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sniffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761584/invalid-oracle-url-specified-with-sniffy) doesn't work with `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource`

See more details in this question: [Invalid Oracle URL specified with Sniffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761584/invalid-oracle-url-specified-with-sniffy)

Comment: Thanks @bedrin for your help. To be able to see Sniffy response times I have removed `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` from glassfish-resources.xml configuration file. In Payara server console I also updated JDBC connection pool settings (**Resource Type:** `java.sql.Driver`, **Driver Classname:** `io.sniffy.MockDriver`).