# Invalid Oracle URL specified with Sniffy

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink, sniffy

I'm trying to configure Sniffy to work with Oracle. I'm using Glassfish as application server, with JPA 2.0, and EclipseLink as provider.

When EclipseLink tries to allocate the connection, it fails saying that the Oracle URL specified is invalid, because of the `"sniffer:"` prefix, I guess:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because:  Invalid Oracle URL specified
Error Code: 0
```

This is how I configured the pool in my domain.xml file:

```
<jdbc-resource pool-name="poolGI" object-type="system-all" jndi-name="jdbc/poolGI" />
<jdbc-connection-pool driver-classname="io.sniffy.MockDriver" name="poolGI" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="sniffer:jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service)))"></property>
    <property name="user" value="user"></property>
    <property name="password" value="password"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Comment: "it says" ? What says ? Post the EXCEPTION + STACK TRACE for that message and then people know where it is coming from!

Comment: The STACK TRACE does give information.

Comment: I'm afraid that's all there is in the log

Answer (score 0):

[Sniffy](http://sniffy.io/) developer here.

Looks like `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource` ignores the `driver-classname` property and implicitly uses `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`. OracleDriver doesn't know about `sniffer:` schema, hence the exception.

You need to switch to another data source in order to use Sniffy.
For example [Hikari Connection Pool](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).